# WebForms equivalent of MVC's "return Content()"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, braintree

I am trying to verify an endpoint for [Braintree's webhook notifications](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/webhooks). They are sending me a `GET` request with a parameter that I need to use in one of their functions.

I would imagine I am suppose to send a `POST` request back, but not sure of the correct implementation. What would be the web forms equivalent of MVC's `return Content()`?

```
public class WebhooksController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Accept()
  {
    return Content(Constants.Gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way but you could make a [generic handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // here you have access to context.Request and context.Response
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```